# Flowchart symbol or pattern for Publisher/Subscriber or Listen/Notify

Tags: pubsub, flowchart

We have a system consisting of

- `Detectors`
- `Converters/Transformers`
- `Business Rules Engines` and `State Managers`
- `Views/Displays/Applications`

There are several potential ways these may interact and share state

- Message passing mediated by Queues
- Point to Point Message Passing via `Http`
- Shared State in a Database/Datastore and state-change notifications via messaging

I am drawing up a simplistic flow-chart / system diagram and am wondering how best to represent the publish-subscribe or notifier/listener(s) mechansisms.  I do not recall standardized flowchart symbols for these.

An example would be:

```
1  A Parts Modification detection event occurs

2  Events are written to `Events` and `Parts_State` topics (or possibly tables)

3  A State_Management module that listens on those topics performs validations and 
   transformations then updates downstream topics with the results
```

What I am looking for is how to represent the *Publisher/Notifier* aspect of the Detection module in the Flowchart and the *Subscriber/Listener* aspect of the State_Management module in the flowchart.

Comment: Flowcharts were invented before pub/sub architecture was invented.  There are no standard symbols.  You can borrow from another standard for that.

Comment: OK .. any recommendations ?